# Using custom C# attributes to select Fluent conventions

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent, custom-attributes

Suppose you have sets of Fluent conventions that apply to specific groups of mappings, but not to all of them.

My thought here was, I'll create custom C# attributes that I can apply to the Fluent *Map classes - and write conventions that determine acceptance by inspecting the *Map class to see if the custom attribute was applied.

That way, I can select groups of conventions and apply them to various mappings by just tagging them with a custom attribute - [UseShortNamingConvention], etc.

I'm new to NHibernate (and Fluent, and C# for that matter) - is this approach possible?

And is it sane? :-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is! Ive actually done something similiar but went with Marker Interfaces instead (INotCacheable, IComponent), but Marker Interface or Attribute, should't be that much of a difference.

When applying your conventions, just check for the presence of your attribute and ur good :)

EDIT:

Adding some code samples

```
    public class MyMappingConventions : IReferenceConvention, IClassConvention
    {
        public void Apply(IOneToManyCollectionInstance instance)
        {
            instance.Key.Column(instance.EntityType.Name + "ID");
            instance.LazyLoad();
            instance.Inverse();
            instance.Cascade.SaveUpdate();

            if ((typeof(INotCacheable).IsAssignableFrom(instance.Relationship.Class.GetUnderlyingSystemType())))
                return;

            instance.Cache.ReadWrite();
        }

        public void Apply(IClassInstance instance)
        {
            instance.Table(instance.EntityType.Name + "s");
            //If inheriting from IIMutable make it readonly
            if ((typeof(IImmutable).IsAssignableFrom(instance.EntityType)))
                instance.ReadOnly();

            //If not cacheable
            if ((typeof(INotCacheable).IsAssignableFrom(instance.EntityType)))
                return;

            instance.Cache.ReadWrite();
        }
}
```

Comment: Do you know how? ... instance.EntityType will give me the type of entity being mapped - is there a property that will give me the EntityMapType?